# Serious amount of bluescreens when using Ableton Live 9.2.1 on Windows 10/8.1

Tags: audio, drivers, crash

Today I wanted to have another studio session using [Ableton Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ableton_Live), but my PC kept me from it. I had be working for around half an hour when I got the first [bluescreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death), `SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION` it said. So I let the system reboot and reopened the project from the undo history. Then five minutes later I got `CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT`, so I tried again. This kept happening like five more times giving me other weird error messages which I did not have time for to write down. They all differed.

I then tried to see if there was something different than a normal studio session of mine. I remember that it has happened before a few times back when I used Windows 8.1 (I'm now on Windows 10)

I've looked on the Internet to see what the errors meant, but I didn't understand and so I'm not able to track down what's causing it.

Could it be my audio (ASIO) driver? Or my USB 3G receiver?

I tried disabling them both, but I still got another two bluescreens.

How can I track down what's causing the error? What might it be?

Comment: Use windbg to determine which system file (driver or otherwise) is causing this problem.  You provided so little information we can't do this for you.

Comment: You better tell what codes the BSOD shows - 0x...

Comment: @Alexiy where can i find that?

Comment: When you see a blue screen, there is a error code at the bottom which begins with 0x. You should tell this code.

Comment: I've tried to make it happen again to getthose codes but with no luck. It does not crash anymore...